# Excel formula to check the last non zero value in row and bring cell value from corresponding column

Tags: excel, formula, lookup

can you please advise how to write a formula to :

- identify the last non zero value in row
- bring the value from another row at corresponding column
- example below

---

```
Karl   Jane   Adam   Pete     Dona    
300       0     200     100      0
```

---

- the result should be Pete
- I tried Lookup to and can find the last non zero value is 100 but how to bring the value from another row?
  Thank you
  Tom

Answer (score 2):

Using just the `LOOKUP` formula, you merely set your `result_vector` argument to the row from which you want to get the result.

Try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A2:E2>0),$A$1:$E$1)
```

*(If your formula is not in the same row, you can use whole-row references)*

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(2:2>0),$1:$1)
```

Answer (score 1):

To stick with `LOOKUP`, you could use it in `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(1:1,LOOKUP(2,1/(2:2>0),COLUMN(2:2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula XLOOKUP:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,1/(A2:E2>0),A1:E1,"",-1,-1)
```

[image]